# Validar que un texto tenga exactamente 3 números con expresión regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero validar en JavaScript que el usuario o contraseña solo acepten exactamente 3 números con expresión regular.

Tengo lo siguiente, el problema es que cuando ingreso `1234` me lo acepta como correcto, necesito validar esto para poder realizar el resto de mi página.

```
function validar() {
    usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;

    patron = /\d{3}/;
    if(patron.test(usuario)){
        alert("correcto")
    }else{
        alert("ERROR")

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: @Richard ¿El texto en `usuario` son solamente 3 dígitos o es algo como `nombre123`? ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo en tu pregunta? Idealmente, todas las preguntas de regex [deberían tener](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) diferentes ejemplos de texto contra el cual intenta que coincidan y casos en los cuales no debería coincidir... Y si es algo más que esos 3 dígitos, ¿qué caracteres podría tener el resto del nombre?

Comment: usuario podra llevar letras y numeros, la contraseña tiene que llevar 3 numeros y  letras exactamente, 6 caracteres en total repartido en 3 y 3..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vayamos por partes, de más sencillo a más complicado, y simplificando todo en el final.

**1. Sólo 3 dígitos**

Si fuese sólo ver si tiene 3 dígitos, ¿para qué usar regex? Es un número entre 100 y 999, ¿no?

```
if (usuario > 99 && usuario < 1000) {
    //válido
}
```

---

**2. 3 dígitos en el final**

Pero si el usuario es un nombre terminado en 3 dígitos, entonces tenemos que garantizarnos que el regex coincida desde el inicio (`^`) hasta el final del texto (`$`).

Recordemos que una expresión regular coincide con **cualquier parte del texto** (con la primera que encuentre). Por eso tu código fallaba, porque coincidía con los primeros 3 dígitos dentro de los 4 que tenía el texto.

```
textoterminadoen1234
//              ^^^
//       coincide con estos 3
```

Entonces, forzamos a que coincida con la posición inicial, cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean dígitos, los 3 dígitos, y la posición final del texto.

```
/^\D*\d{3}$/
```

- `\D` coincide con 1 caracter, cualquiera que no sea un dígito (es lo mismo que `[^0-9]`; y el `*` lo repite entre 0 e infinitas veces.

```js
document
    .getElementById('usuario')
    .addEventListener('input',validar);


function validar() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value,
        resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    patron = /^\D*\d{3}$/;
    if(patron.test(usuario)){
        resultado.innerText = "correcto";
    }else{
        resultado.innerText = "ERROR";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

---

**3. Regex para exactamente 3 dígitos en cualquier posición**

Ahora, si pueden estar en cualquier parte, hay que permitir `\D*` entre medio de cada uno, que sería algo como `/^\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*$/`.

Pero se puede hacer más simple, usando un grupo `(?:`…`)` y repitiendo a ese grupo:

```
/^(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$/
```

```js
document
    .getElementById('usuario')
    .addEventListener('input',validar);


function validar() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value,
        resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    patron = /^(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$/;
    if(patron.test(usuario)){
        resultado.innerText = "correcto";
    }else{
        resultado.innerText = "ERROR";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

---

**4. Eliminar todo lo que no es un dígito**

Pero quizás, te sea mucho más sencillo eliminar todo, dejando sólo los dígitos y usando lo mismo que en el primer punto:

```js
document
    .getElementById('usuario')
    .addEventListener('input',validar);


function validar() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value,
        resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    var soloDigitos = usuario.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    if(soloDigitos > 99 && soloDigitos < 1000){
        resultado.innerText = "correcto";
    }else{
        resultado.innerText = "ERROR";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema con tu expresión es que si escribes un texto que tenga 3 números seguidos, esta va a retornar true debido a que eso es lo que tu expresión significa.

Tienes que indicarle que desde el principio hasta el final del string, solo contenga 3 numeros utilizando `^` al principio y `$` al final:

```js
function validar() {

  usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;

    patron = /^[0-9]{3}$/;
    if(patron.test(usuario)){
        alert("correcto")
    }else{
        alert("ERROR")
    }

}
```

```html
<input id="usuario" type="text" />

<button onclick="validar()"> Validar</button>
```

`^` significa que busque al inicio del string y `$` al final.

Comment: El `[0-9]` se ve feo pudiendo usar `\d`.